# How can pyspark infer double quoted integers with leading zeros (eg. 000000038473) as string?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to infer schema with pyspark using infer schema :

```
self.spark.read.option('inferSchema', 'true')
```

But when the number has double quote, pyspark infers integer instead of string (for example when the number has "leading zeros"). In this case, i want Pyspark to infer strings, not integers.

How can i force pyspark to understand that this is a string, without removing the inferSchema.

**i want to keep InferSchema. It is helpful for other columns, eg. floats, or other integers. We are doing a type detection kind of ingestion.**

[image]

The only way i found so far is by using :

- `option("quote","")` when reading, which put double quote on every string and **every number having leading zeros**.
- Then i have to remove these double quotes which ugly `regexp_replace` such as eg : `regexp_replace(SNumber,'"','') as s_number` on each of these
  columns.

Is there a better way to do it ? **We don't want to define a schema and "apply schema" at this stage.**

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: why do you have blank as quote `option("quote","")` if your quote character is `"`? shouldn't that be `option("quote",'"')`?

Comment: if i write option("quote",'"'), those leading zeros integers are read as integers, not strings

Answer (score 0):

You can define a schema and read it that will solve the issue. Also spark does the implicit conversion , even though if the column is string and it contains only numeric values it converts to double and does any operation

example file

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/inbound/1.csv
"A","B","00001234353"
"D","E","000012312"
```

**Code and Proof that it is reading as Integer using defining Schema.**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = spark.read.csv("/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/inbound/1.csv")
df.show()

+---+---+-----------+
|_c0|_c1|        _c2|
+---+---+-----------+
|  A|  B|00001234353|
|  D|  E|  000012312|
+---+---+-----------+

schema = StructType([
StructField('name', StringType(),True), \
StructField('Desc', StringType(),True), \
StructField('value', IntegerType(),True)
])
df = spark.read.csv("/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/inbound/1.csv",schema=schema)
df.show()

+----+----+-------+
|name|Desc|  value|
+----+----+-------+
|   A|   B|1234353|
|   D|   E|  12312|
+----+----+-------+
```

**Implicit Conversion**

```
df = spark.read.csv("/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/inbound/1.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df.show()
+---+---+-----------+
|_c0|_c1|        _c2|
+---+---+-----------+
|  A|  B|00001234353|
|  D|  E|  000012312|
+---+---+-----------+
```

Adding 0 to the columns implicitly converts to decimal

```
df1=spark.sql("select _c1,_c0,_c2 + 0 as _c2 from table1")

>>> df1.show()
+---+---+---------+
|_c1|_c0|      _c2|
+---+---+---------+
|  B|  A|1234353.0|
|  E|  D|  12312.0|
+---+---+---------+

>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: double (nullable = true)

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks buthis does not solve my issue. I want to use infer schema as we are doing a schema and type drift detection. We are using "apply schema" later in the ingestion process.
By the way i don't want to ingest leading zeros integers as integers, i want to ingest them as strings.